# Issue multiple commands in ubuntu terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

I'm using ubuntu 18.04 server edition and I'm in terminal.

`# hdparm -I /dev/sd[a-c] | grep "/dev\|level\|Model"`

will issue the equivalent of

```
# hdparm -I /dev/sda | grep "/dev\|level\|Model"
# hdparm -I /dev/sdb | grep "/dev\|level\|Model"
# hdparm -I /dev/sdc | grep "/dev\|level\|Model"
```

However

`# smartctl --nocheck standby -i /dev/sd[a-c] | grep "Model\|Power"`

will only give me

```
# smartctl --nocheck standby -i /dev/sda | grep "Model\|Power"
```

and it doesn't issue the command for /dev/sdb and /dev/sdc

How can I achieve the desired effect?

Thanks

Kiwi

Comment: You have to run them one-by-one. Command expansion doesn't work like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command expansion works in-line and does not expand into multiple commands. If you `set -x` in your shell, you can see the command that it actually executes.

For the first command

```
# hdparm -I /dev/sd[a-c] | grep "/dev\|level\|Model"
```

Provided that `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdc` all exist, the actual command run would be

```
# hdparm -I /dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdc | grep "/dev\|level\|Model"
```

And it's the `hdparm` program that processes multiple arguments and produces the same output as if three separate commands were issued.

The real thing is that `smartctl` doesn't process more than one arguments, so at best you must manually run the command against the three devices.

Or you can use a loop:

```
# for arg in /dev/sd[a-c]
> do
>  smartctl --nocheck standby -i "$arg" | grep "Model\|Power"
> done
```

Comment: thank you for explaining that to me :)

Comment: @Kiwijunglist You can click the grey checkmark on the left if you find this answer helpful.